Handling The Size of Categories as Foundational Theories
This question is a followup on a previous one (Category Theory built on Type Theories, Category theory as foundations), with this one meant to focus on a point brought up in the discussion. Namely, the original question was about if category actually served as a foundation for mathematics, or if it was simply a toolbox built on top of set theory or type theory.
Also, because I feel this can potentially be something people have different definitions of, here is my rough notion of foundations, for context: A foundation for mathematics is a “set” ;) of axioms, with which one can prove standard mathematical results in topology/analysis/algebra.
Now, as for the new question, if category theory can, on its own, serve as a foundation for mathematics, I am confused how it does so, given that when category theory is built off of set/type theories, one has to be careful with higher categories, since some set/type theories are not robust enough to handle “sets/types of all sets/types.”
In short, how does category theory as a foundation handle issues regarding the hierarchy of categories, if the fundamental pieces are objects and morphisms, instead of sets and types? For instance, does higher category theory have to be brought in axiomatically? Is it an extension of regular categories in the same way second-order logic is an extension of first-order logic?
Apologies if some of these points are incoherent. I am not a specialist in mathematical logic.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
